# Show attribute if product is Out-Of-Stock Magento

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento, zend-framework

I need to know how to Show attribute if product is Out-Of-Stock in magento.
If my product is in stock, the attribute is shown, otherwise not.

If i set a product to **QTY=0 (Out Of Stock)**. Attribute like 'size' is missing. Why? Can anyone explain this please? I already made a research but any good answer.

- I can't provide any code for this question. Sorry about this.

Comment: what is the product type? configurable product or simple product with custom options?

Comment: @Ansyori I have both simple/configurable product types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to your template's product page, the base directory for the default template is: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
 <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <!-- ... !-->
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Perhaps your theme only chooses to display certain attributes IF the product is saleable (i.e not out of stock)